# x86 assembly idioms

Tags: assembly, x86, idioms

I've been trying to get a good hold on the x86 assembly language, and was wondering if there was a quick-and-short equivalent of `movl $1, %eax`. That's when I thought that a list of idioms used frequently in the language would perhaps be a good idea.

This could include the preferred use of `xorl %eax, %eax` as opposed to `movl $0, %eax`, or `testl %eax, %eax` against `cmpl $0, %eax`.

Oh, and kindly post one example per post!

Comment: `movl $1, %eax` is pretty quick and short. On some processors, `xorl %eax, %eax` is actually slower than `movl $0, %eax`. On others, `incl %eax` is slower than `addl $1, %eax`. If you are going to the trouble of writing assembly in 2010, you should know for what architecture you are writing and select your "dialect" (to keep with the linguistic metaphor) in consequence.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq, could you please explain what factors affect this sort of a difference in performance? I am especially baffled by `incl %eax` being slower than `addl $1, %eax`. Additionally, if you could point me to some link which details this sort of behaviour, I will be grateful!

Comment: For all x86 architectures in 2010 xor eax,eax ist faster or equivalent, in any case it is shorter. Have a look a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396527/any-reason-to-do-a-xor-eax-eax/1396552#1396552. This is pretty much since the days of 486.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. The individual examples mentioned have already been raised in other posts.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another interesting "idiom". Hopefully everyone knows that division is a big time sink even compared to a multiplication. Using a little math, it's possible to multiply by the inverse of constant instead of dividing by it. This goes beyond the shr tricks. For example, to divide by 5:

```
mov eax, some_number
mov ebx, 3435973837    // 32-bit inverse of 5
mul ebx
```

Now eax has been divided by 5 without using the slow div opcode. Here is a list of useful constants for division shameless stolen from http://blogs.msdn.com/devdev/archive/2005/12/12/502980.aspx

```
3   2863311531
5   3435973837
7   3067833783
9   954437177
11  3123612579
13  3303820997
15  4008636143
17  4042322161
```

For numbers not on the list, you might need to do a shift beforehand (to divide by 6, shr 1, then multiply by the inverse of 3).

Answer (score 7):

on x64:

```
xor eax, eax
```

for

```
xor rax, rax
```

(the first one also implicitly clears the upper half of `rax`, but has a smaller opcode)

Answer (score 7):

Using `LEA` for e.g. multiplication, like:

```
lea eax, [ecx+ecx*4]
```

for EAX = 5 * ECX

Comment: BTW: this is dog slow on NetBurst, because Intel removed the barrel-shifter in order to be able to obtain higher clock speeds. Ironically, at the time the P4 came out, this was still documented in Intel's optimization manuals.

Comment: Thanks for the comment re. speed. I realise that an idiom is not necessarily the same thing as an optimisation. However, as an idiom, I think LEA has been fairly widely (ab)used.

Comment: Well, it *is* an optimization. And it is even officially recommended by Intel. It's just that, after officially recommending it for 15 years, they suddenly releases a new CPU on which it was slow, thus essentially requiring recompiling *every single program ever written*. Thankfully, NetBurst died a quick and painful death and all current microarchitectures are evolutions of the Pentium III, not the Pentium4, so all current CPUs again have a barrel shifter. Basically, *all* Intel CPUs since 80385 and all Athlons have it, only the Pentium4 doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

You might as well as how to optimize in assembly. Then you'd have to ask what you're optimizing for: size or speed? Anyway, here's my "idiom", a replacement for `xchg`:

```
xor eax, ebx
xor ebx, eax
xor eax, ebx
```

Comment: **WARNING:** If eax == ebx - Both will be zeroed!

Comment: Are you sure about that? 42 ^ 42 = 0 ; 42 ^ 0 = 42 ; 0 ^ 42 = 42

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on my comment:

To an undiscerning processor such as the Pentium Pro, `xorl %eax, %eax` appears to have a dependency on `%eax` and thus must wait for the value of that register to be available. Later processors actually have additional logic to recognize that instruction as not having any dependencies.

The instructions `incl` and `decl` set some of the flags but leave others unchanged. That's the worst situation if the flags are modelized as a single register for the purpose of instruction reordering: any instruction that reads a flag after an `incl` or `decl` must be considered as depending on the `incl` or `decl` (in case it's reading one of the flags that this instruction sets) and also on the previous instruction that set the flags (in case it's reading one of the flags that this instruction does not set). A solution would be to divide the flags register into two and to consider dependencies with this finer grain... but AMD had a better idea and removed these instructions entirely from the 64-bit extension they proposed a few years back.

Regarding the links, I found this either in the Intel manuals for which it's useless to provide a link because they are on a corporate website that's reorganized every six months, or on Agner Fog's site: http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals

Answer (score 5):

At loops...

```
  dec     ecx 
  cmp     ecx, -1       
  jnz     Loop
```

is

```
  dec     ecx  
  jns     Loop
```

Faster and shorter.

Comment: Isn't loop .Loop easier?

Comment: @Hasan Saad: It is but ti is slower, using loop in x86 is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
I had no idea about that so thanks for the information. Highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `SHL` and `SHR` for multiplication/division by a power of 2

Comment: It can be extended to other numbers as well. E.g., `y*320 = (y << 8) + (y << 6)`. That may not always be faster than a simple multiplication, though. Depends on your processor.

Answer (score 2):

Another one (beside `xor`) for

```
mov eax, 0   ; B800000000h
```

is

```
sub eax, eax ; 29C0h
```

Rationale: smaller opcode

Answer (score 2):

Don't know whether this counts as an idiom, but on most processors prior to i7

```
movq xmm0, [eax]
movhps xmm0, [eax+8]
```

or, if SSE3 is available,

```
lddqu xmm0, [eax]
```

are faster for reading from an unaligned memory location than

```
movdqu xmm0, [eax]
```

Answer (score 1):

The earliest reference to division by invariant integers that is more than just an inverse multiply is here:
[Torbjörn Granlund of The Royal Institue of Technology in Stockholm](http://www.nada.kth.se/~tege/). Check out his publications