# Understanding XOR PHP

Tags: php, xor

I am writing section in my program to update a user, and there is password and confirm passwords.  I dont want to do anything to the password field in the DB unless they have filled the fields in.

So I have error checking for:

```
if(($sql['password']!="") && ($sql['cpassword']!=""))
            {
                if($sql['password'] == $sql['cpassword'])
                {
//update
}
```

}

However I want to write a quick line to throw an error message if they only filled out one of the password fields.  So I figured:

```
if($sql['password'] ^ $sql['cpassword']) 
            {
                echo You must fill out <i>both</i> password fields and they <i>must</i> match.";
            }
```

Would do it, but It doesnt seem to.  Then I added a NOT operator, !, and that seemed to work well, however if both fields have *nothing* in them, I still get the error message :(

From the logic I can see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749620/1445985) answer, It would seem that simple XOR would work.  But
But it doesnt, Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: `if(($sql['password'] != "") && ($sql['password' == $sql['cpassword'])) { ...`

should propably solve your problem.

Comment: the answer you accepted is going to cause you problems. it is only accidental that it seems to work... it doesn't work correctly at all.

Answer (score 3):

XOR certainly is not what you want here.

As David states, XOR will return a "true" result if the values are different, however when you XOR two strings the XOR operation is only done up to the point of the shortest string.

Examples

`'AAAA' ^ 'AAAA'` This returns an empty string (false-equivalent value) as the values are the same.

`'AAAA' ^ 'bbbb'` This returns an non-empty string (true-equivalent value)..

`'AAAA' ^ 'AAAAbbbb'` This returns an empty string (false-equivalent value), even though the strings are different. This is because the result of the operation only considers the first 4 characters.

In Sandy Lee's example `(bool)$string` does not really help.

`(bool)'0'` = false

`(bool)'1'` = true

This does not tell you if the string is empty or not. It simply gives you the boolean-equivalent value of the string.

There is no need to use XOR here at all. It's not the right tool for the job. There is no need to try and do anything fancy either, the simple tools work perfectly.

```
$password = trim($password);
$confirm = trim($confirm);

if (!$password || !$confirm) {
    // One of the fields was not completed.
}
elseif ($password !== $confirm) {
    // Fields did not match
}
else {
    // Update password
}
```

Comment: aargh! this is eating my head now! `(bool)'0'=false` but `(bool)'00'=true`. what is this?

Comment: Why `(bool)'00'` is `true`?

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167 See [Converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). '0' is a special case string.

Comment: so my solution is right unless the one of the string is 0 and the other is empty. And in this case the strings have to be typecasted into booleans it won't work out if XOR is operated directly on strings. Well, I would never recommend XOR for such thing but the questioner wanted it in this way ('...XOR would work...'). Thanks for your explanation.