# How to XOR between a byte and a word on PDP-11?

Tags: assembly, pdp-11

The main problem we encountered is that one number is saved as a byte, the other is saved as a word and we realize that there's a built in `XOR` in PDP-11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749585/what-is-the-meaning-of-xor-in-x86-assembly

Comment: @PosticaÐenis I think the user's problem is that he wants to do this on PDP-11 architecture.

Comment: So zero-extend the shorter one or truncate the longer one.

Comment: Bytes on PDP-11?

Comment: @MartinRosenau: What's weird about that?  [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture) has 8-bit bytes and 16-bit words.  It's not one of those old architectures with a non-power-of-2 word size.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK. Thanks. I just read your link. I was thinking that PDP-11 works like other "pre-CPU" computers or the modern TMS320 where the memory does not store bytes but 16-bit words (so there are no instructions that can handle bytes).

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Ah yes, right some machines only have word-addressable memory ([the most recent mainstream CPU example being early DEC Alpha in the early 90s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory/46818162#46818162), but also including some modern DSPs)  But they still have bytes, you just have to load + shift&mask if you want them separately.  (But in that case the OP would already know how to deal with bytes using full registers to have stored a byte in the first place)

Answer (score 4):

The `XOR` instruction on the PDP-11 only works on 16-bit words.

You will have to make a 16-bit word out of the byte operand first. Whether that is zero-extension or sign-extension (maybe `SXT` can help?) is up to you.

Then apply `XOR` to the two word arguments.