# ++nc vs nc = nc + 1

Tags: c, pre-increment

In K&R Ch 1:

> The statement `++nc` presents a new operator, `++`, which means increment by one. You could instead write `nc = nc + 1`, but `++nc` is more concise and often more efficient.

When would pre-increment be more efficient than the alternative? For most things, at least, the assembly for both is the `add` (edit: or `inc`) instruction. When do they differ?

Comment: I know this is tagged C, and correct me if I'm wrong, but as a curiosity, I believe post increment may be slower than pre increment in C++, even on a modern compiler. Because the C++ standard enforces post increment to call the copy constructor of the object. Reference, [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.15).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That text is long out dated. It might have been true in the 70's that compilers would produce more efficient output for ++n, but not any more. All modern compilers will produce identical code.

Comment: To clarify - The `++` operator was initially added to C back when C compilers were dumb and did no optimization, so `x = x + 1`, `x += 1` and `x++` all possibly compiled to different assembly code. Nowadays, of course, compilers are much smarter than that.

Comment: I guess I'm just too young. Thanks for the help.

Comment: aww, now you're making me feel old!  -;)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, true for all "normal" cases, but there is one exception when `nc` is `volatile` qualified.

Comment: @Jens can you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 3):

> For most things, at least, the assembly for both is the add instruction.

That's not quite true: there is often a [separate "increment by one" instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993326/relative-performance-of-x86-inc-vs-add-instruction). However, that's irrelevant since any half-decent compiler will produce identical machine code for `++nc` and `nc = nc + 1`.

In other words, there is no performance difference. There may have been when the book was written and compilers were not very good, but there isn't anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure, I'm just thinking out aloud (maybe I shouldn't): Perhaps in K&R's time, `++nc` was compiled into something more efficient than `nc = nc + 1` (e.g., an increment instruction, rather than an addition). Nowadays, however, compilers probably optimise this automagically.

Comment: I believe `++` was added to early C precisely _because_ no one had written compilers complex enough to use the increment instructions automatically.

Comment: There were good enough compilers available at the time, just not on the 24 kB machine that K&R had when writing the first C compiler. It was a *mini-computer* fitting in a single room. :-)  http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/ken-and-den.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is what I could see with `gcc -S <filename>`. I'll let you derive what you want!

```
>
> cat 1.c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int i=0;
        ++i;

        return 0;
    }

>
> cat 2.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    i++;

    return 0;
}

>
> cat 3.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    i = i + 1;

    return 0;
}
>
> gcc -S 1.c 2.c 3.c
>
>
> diff 1.s 2.s
1c1
<       .file   "1.c"
---
>       .file   "2.c"
>
> diff 2.s 3.s
1c1
<       .file   "2.c"
---
>       .file   "3.c"
>
> diff 3.s 1.s
1c1
<       .file   "3.c"
---
>       .file   "1.c"
>
>
```

The below is the content of the `.s` file for `1.c` and the instructions are identical when compared with 2.s and 3.s!

```
> cat 1.s
        .file   "1.c"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
        pushq   %rbp
.LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI1:
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
.LFE2:
        .size   main, .-main
        .section        .eh_frame,"a",@progbits
.Lframe1:
        .long   .LECIE1-.LSCIE1
.LSCIE1:
        .long   0x0
        .byte   0x1
        .string "zR"
        .uleb128 0x1
        .sleb128 -8
        .byte   0x10
        .uleb128 0x1
        .byte   0x3
        .byte   0xc
        .uleb128 0x7
        .uleb128 0x8
        .byte   0x90
        .uleb128 0x1
        .align 8
.LECIE1:
.LSFDE1:
        .long   .LEFDE1-.LASFDE1
.LASFDE1:
        .long   .LASFDE1-.Lframe1
        .long   .LFB2
        .long   .LFE2-.LFB2
        .uleb128 0x0
        .byte   0x4
        .long   .LCFI0-.LFB2
        .byte   0xe
        .uleb128 0x10
        .byte   0x86
        .uleb128 0x2
        .byte   0x4
        .long   .LCFI1-.LCFI0
        .byte   0xd
        .uleb128 0x6
        .align 8
.LEFDE1:
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
>
```

Answer (score 1):

For "normal" variables there should be no difference as other answers suggest. Only if `nc` is `voloatile` qualified the result could be different. For such a variable the `+1` form *must* first evaluate the expression `nc` that is load `nc` and then perform the addition. For the `++` form the compiler still could take shortcuts and increment the variable in place.