# Why does ICC produce "inc" instead of "add" in assembly on x86?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, increment, icc

While fiddling with simple C code, I noticed something strange. Why does ICC produces `incl %eax` in assembly code generated for increment instead of `addl $1, %eax`? GCC behaves as expected though, using `add`.

Example code (`-O3` used on both GCC and ICC)

```
int A, B, C, D, E;

void foo()
{
    A = B + 1;
    B = 0;
    C++;
    D++;
    D++;
    E += 2;
}
```

Result on ICC

```
L__routine_start_foo_0:
foo:
    movl      B(%rip), %eax                                 #5.13
    movl      D(%rip), %edx                                 #8.9
    incl      %eax                                          #5.17
    movl      E(%rip), %ecx                                 #10.9
    addl      $2, %edx                                      #9.9
    addl      $2, %ecx                                      #10.9
    movl      %eax, A(%rip)                                 #5.9
    movl      $0, B(%rip)                                   #6.9
    incl      C(%rip)                                       #7.9
    movl      %edx, D(%rip)                                 #9.9
    movl      %ecx, E(%rip)                                 #10.9
    ret
```

For example, see [here](http://goo.gl/WThWRw).

As such, I'm wondering - is this an intended feature, a bug or some quirk resulting from some specific setting? If `add` is (supposedly) better due to flags update or efficiency (which is the conclusion based on the links below) - why does ICC use `inc`?

Related:

[Relative performance of x86 inc vs. add instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993326/relative-performance-of-x86-inc-vs-add-instruction)

[Is ADD 1 really faster than INC ? x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383407/is-add-1-really-faster-than-inc-x86)

[GCC doesn't make use of inc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890157/gcc-doesnt-make-use-of-inc)

Note:

I'm asking this question explicitly because none of the questions I found or was directed to on SO does explain this behaviour. My previous question concerning this matter got closed because, supposedly, it's *trivial* and *has been answered*. I don't find it trivial. I didn't find an answer in all of the links and answers given. It's not another "how to plug my mouse into my PC" problem. All of the questions explain why `add` is/could be better on new x86 processors or why GCC uses it, but none concerns ICC.

Any insight on ICC design choices would be also very welcome.

PS I don't consider "it does it because it does" a valid answer.

Comment: It would help if you included the C source and assembly listing in your question. Why would `inc` be incorrect? C source code specifies *behavior*; as long as the program behaves correctly, it doesn't matter (as far as the C standard is concerned) what instructions are used to achieve that behavior. But yes, there might be reasons to prefer `addl` over `incl`; it would also be helpful if you'd cite some sources that explain why

Comment: Don't keep the compiler options you selected a secret.  You already know that optimizing for size makes INC likely to be used.

Comment: The flags issue is only an issue if you follow it up with a branch that reads the carry flag, which is unlikely.

Comment: As I understand it, icc is closed source, which might make it very difficult to get any insight about the design choices that went into it.

Comment: BTW, along with `inc`, `dec` is prefered over `sub`. Does anyone know whether `icc` must apply that operation as reported in the document?

Comment: Sandy Bridge was the first processor that did something about the partial flag stall that INC suffers from.  It still isn't clear what micro-architecture is being targeted.

Comment: [`inc/dec` was slow on P4, but not on anything else](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36510865/224132).  `inc` itself doesn't cause a partial flag stall, only reading `CF` after an `inc`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not unreasonable to assume at this point that *incl* was selected as it takes only one byte (0x40) instead of three (0x83 0xc0 0x01).

Comment: Perhaps some Intel processors are fast on `incl` (while AMD could be slower?)?

Comment: There was a time when lea eax,[1+eax] was faster, but that may have only been true on 16 bit processor so only lea ax,[1+ax].

Comment: The one-byte inc/dec has been deprecated in x86_64 (which is the case of the OP), because those opcodes were used for [REX prefix](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix)

Comment: `inc eax` must be encoded s `FF C0` in x86_64, which is not 1 byte, but still shorter than `add eax, 1`