# how to set the code that c++ compiler generate

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to change the code the compiler create in the exe file?

I am trying to change the output code of the compiler like that:

The code that I am writing in the cpp file is:

```
a++;
```

And the compiler generate it the the folowing code:

```
INC [a]
```

How can I change it to this:

```
ADD [a],1
```

I want that the compiler will do it every time the compiler compile this statement and that is why the asm statement do not work.Also I want to change it only on one platform.

I am sure that the compiler generate the code based on a template so how can I change it(if I can)?

Comment: Even with optimizations turned off, chances are most compilers will opt for `INC` instead of `ADD 1`. Is there a specific reason why you want your compiler to prefer the latter to the former?

Comment: Which compiler? If add is faster than inc on some processor, asking the compiler to tune for this processor may be sufficient.

Comment: _'I am sure that the compiler generate the code based on a template'_ Nope! It doesn't work like this, it's a much more complex process than template substitution.

Comment: I want to do this for more complex statement.
It was just an example.
Except that I think that the code taken from a template because it is the same all the time except the number(like in for)

Comment: If you want to control the output code, write the `asm` yourself.

Comment: "On some micro-architectures, with some instruction streams, INC will incur a "partial flags update stall" (because it updates some of the flags while preserving the others). ADD sets the value of all of the flags, and so does not risk such a stall." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383407/is-add-1-really-faster-than-inc-x86

Comment: @StoryTeller you need to edit the compiler, not the assembler, to emit `add` instead of `inc`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, or you can just write [inline assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler)

Comment: If you need to dwelve on such details, you might write the assembly for every platform you need. From the C++ or C point of view, there's no such thing as an assembly.

Comment: But I can see the assembly code in the debug and it is the same for every loop or if or other statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just use inline assembly. For example in GCC:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_X86
    __asm__ ( "addl $1, %0" : "=r"(a) : : "memory" );
#else
    a++;
#endif
```

Comment: But if I want that my program can run on every machin that will not work.I will need to write the asm every place in the code too.

Comment: @user13342203 Then, just use `#ifdef`!