# Using Int (32 bits) over char (8 bits) to 'help' processor

Tags: c

In C, often we use char for small number representations. However Processor always uses Int( or 32 bit) values for read from(or fetch from) registers. So every time we need to use a char or 8 bits in our program processor need to fetch 32 bits from regsiter and 'parse' 8 bits out of it. 
Hence does it sense to use Int more often in place of char if memory is not the limitation? 
Will it 'help' processor?

Comment: It depends. On lots of things. Profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ARM system developers guide

"most ARM data processing operations are 32-bit only. For this reason, you should use
a 32-bit datatype, int or long, for local variables wherever possible. Avoid using char and
short as local variable types, even if you are manipulating an 8- or 16-bit value"

an example code from the book to prove the point. note the wrap around handling for char as opposed to unsigned int.

```html
int checksum_v1(int *data)
{
char i;
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
sum += data[i];
}
return sum;
}
```

ARM7 assembly when using i as a char

```html
checksum_v1
MOV r2,r0 ; r2 = data
MOV r0,#0 ; sum = 0
MOV r1,#0 ; i = 0
checksum_v1_loop
LDR r3,[r2,r1,LSL #2] ; r3 = data[i]
ADD r1,r1,#1 ; r1 = i+1
AND r1,r1,#0xff ; i = (char)r1
CMP r1,#0x40 ; compare i, 64
ADD r0,r3,r0 ; sum += r3
BCC checksum_v1_loop ; if (i<64) loop
MOV pc,r14 ; return sum
```

ARM7 assembly when i is an unsigned int.

```html
checksum_v2
MOV r2,r0 ; r2 = data
MOV r0,#0 ; sum = 0
MOV r1,#0 ; i = 0
checksum_v2_loop
LDR r3,[r2,r1,LSL #2] ; r3 = data[i]
ADD r1,r1,#1 ; r1++
CMP r1,#0x40 ; compare i, 64
ADD r0,r3,r0 ; sum += r3
BCC checksum_v2_loop ; if (i<64) goto loop
MOV pc,r14 ; return sum
```

Answer (score 3):

There's the compiler part and the cpu part.

If you tell the compiler you're using a `char` instead of an `int`, during static analysis it will know the bounds of the variable is between 0-255 instead of 0-(2^32-1). This will allow it to optimize your program better.

On the cpu side, your assumption isn't always correct. Take x86 as an example, it has registers `eax` and `al` for 32 bit and 8 bit register access. If you want to use chars only, using `al` is sufficient. There is no performance loss.

I did some simple benchmarks in response to below comments:

al:

```
format PE GUI 4.0

xor ecx, ecx
dec ecx
loop_start:
inc al
add al, al
dec al
dec al
loopd short loop_start
ret
```

eax:

```
format PE GUI 4.0

xor ecx, ecx
dec ecx
loop_start:
inc eax
add eax, eax
dec eax
dec eax
loopd short loop_start
ret
```

times:

```
$ time ./test_al.exe 
./test_al.exe  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 7.102 total
$ time ./test_eax.exe 
./test_eax.exe  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 7.120 total
```

So in this case, `al` is slightly faster, but sometimes `eax` came out faster. The difference is really negligible. But cpus aren't so simple, there might be code alignment issues, caches, and other things going on, so it's best to benchmark your own code to see if there's any performance improvement. But imo, if your code is not super tight, it's best to trust the compiler to optimize things.

Comment: It's not quite that simple. In ARM using if you are using `char`, then conversion to `int` is costly in both; time and program space. So there is tradeoff between RAM/flash memory usage and in performance.

Comment: Nothing says that operations on `eax` and `al` are the same speed.

Comment: Actually using values smaller than 32 bits in x86 in many cases still reduce performance. You can check it yourself

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Ran some benchmarks, see updated answer.

Comment: your code is simple so the performance may not be different. But in more complex code, using 8 or 16-bit registers may cause the CPU to wait because of a dependency in the high bits. That's why [most x64 instructions zero the upper part of a 32 bit register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm not an expert on cpu design, but from my reading of that answer it appears that using the lower bits only are faster than waiting for the upper bits.

Comment: No, when you only use the lower bits, only part of the register is updated, so the CPU will have to wait for the higher bits if they were modified in another operation. That's because of superscalar and out-of-order execution. The same to eflag/rflags partial update caused by some instructions like [inc and add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383407/is-add-1-really-faster-than-inc-x86)

Comment: "On the cpu side, your assumption isn't correct". Well, it depends on architecture, and "no performance loss" is generally incorrect, esp. in many RISC architectures where you can't do operations on a small part of the register

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc well when the other parts are zeroed the cpu doesn't need to care. You're right about the wording, I made it more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I'd stick to `int` if I were you as that is probably the most native integral type for your platform. Internally you could expect shorter types to be converted to `int` so actually degrading performance.

You should **never** use `char` and expect it to be consistent across platforms. Although the C standard defines `sizeof(char)` to be 1, `char` itself could be `signed` or `unsigned`. The choice is down to the compiler.

If you believe that you can squeeze some performance gain in using an 8 bit type then be explicit and use `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: I noted this in my code which was char treat as signed on amd and x86 machines and when i worked on powerpc char was treat as unsigned char. so Now I'm simply explicitly declaring `signed char` or `usnigned char` So whats the problem?;) EDIT to your EDIT: The compiler defines, but the choice is made by the enviroment (specially cpu arch)

Comment: Oops. Missed that bit out.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is simple enough, the optimizer can do the right thing without you having to worry about it. In this case, plain `int` would be the simplest (and forward-proof) solution.

However, if you want really much to combine specific bit width and speed, you can use *7.18.1.3 Fastest minimum-width integer types* from the C99 standard (requires C99-compliant compiler).

For example:

```
int_fast8_t x;
uint_fast8_t y;
```

are the signed and unsigned types that are guaranteed to be able to store at least 8 bits of data and use the *usually faster* underlying type. Of course, it all depends on what you are doing with the data afterwards.

For example, on all systems I have tested (see: [standard type sizes in C++](http://dev.gentoo.org/~mgorny/types.html)) the fast types were 8-bit long.