# are static / static local SSE / AVX variables blocking a xmm / ymm register?

Tags: c++, sse, avx

When using SSE intrinsics, often zero vectors are required. One way to avoid creating a zero variable inside a function whenever the function is called (each time effectively calling some xor vector instruction) would be to use a static local variable, as in

```
static inline __m128i negate(__m128i a)
{
   static __m128i zero = __mm_setzero_si128();
   return _mm_sub_epi16(zero, a);
}
```

It seems the variable is only initialized when the function is called for the first time. (I checked this by calling a true function instead of the _mm_setzero_si128() intrinsic. It only seems to be possible in C++, not in C, by the way.)

(1) However, once this initialization has happened: Does this block a xmm register for the rest of the program?

(2) Even worse: If such a static local variable is used in multiple functions, would it block multiple xmm registers?

(3) The other way round: If it is *not* blocking a xmm register, would the zero variable always be reloaded from memory when the function is called? Then the static local variable would be pointless since it would be faster to use _mm_setzero_si128().

As an alternative, I was thinking about putting zero into a global static variable that would be initialized at program start:

```
static __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
```

(4) Would the global variable stay in a xmm register while the program runs?

Thanks a lot for your help!

(Since this also applies to AVX intrinsics, I also added the AVX tag.)

Comment: 1 and 2, create 16 functions with 16 statics and see if compiles and runs. 4, create 16 globals and see if it compiles and runs. 3 is subject to compiler optimizations. (btw, you're micro-optimizing because zeroing a register is basically free on current processors)

Comment: [microarchitectural-zeroing-of-a-register-via-the-register-renamer-performance-v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981447/microarchitectural-zeroing-of-a-register-via-the-register-renamer-performance-v)

Comment: Your question would be more interesting if you were broadcasting a non zero value e.g. `_mm_set1_epi32(-1)`.

Comment: It turns out that `-1` is special as well. So broadcasting anything but `0` and `-1` would be interesting. e.g. `_mm_set1_epi32(1)`.

Comment: Thanks @Zboson, for the two helpful links. With respect to your last comment: why is -1 special as well? Also, I had a look at broadcasting operations (at least for -mssse3) and they seem to be quite costly (compiling to two instructions, one of them a vector shuffle).

Comment: @Ralf, I'm still looking into this. I'll try and get back to you tomorrow. `-1` is not as special as `0` but it's still more special than `1` :-)

Comment: If you want to  uses a global register then use e.g. `register __m128i one asm ("xmm15") = _mm_set1_epi32(1);` outside of the functions like you would with a global variable. I don't know how safe this is. I don't know if this is blocking or GCC will clobber at will. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering the question that should really be asked here: you should not be worrying about this *at all*.  Zeroing a register via `xor` effectively costs nothing at all most of the time.  Modern x86 processors recognize this idiom and handle the zeroing directly in register rename; no µop needs to issue at all.  The only time this can slow you down is if you are bound by the front-end, but that is a rather rare situation to be in.

While variations on these questions might be worth pondering in other circumstances (and Mystical's comment gives some good leads on how to answer them yourself), you should really just use `setzero` and call it a day.

Comment: I wasn't aware (or I forgot) that this was handled for free by the register renaming. That's really cool. I read up on it a bit http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/the-surprising-subtleties-of-zeroing-a-register/ Apparently SB has a physical zero register and it just renames the register to the zero register which is why it does not take a µop.

Comment: I guess this only applies to SB and beyond so zeroing costs at least 1 µop on Nehalem?

Comment: Yes, zeroing is "free" only from SNB on.  For Merom-Westmere (iirc), it requires a µop, but is still dependency-breaking (and it's a port 0|1|5 µop, so unless your code is extremely dense, it will issue without any perf impact).

Comment: @Zboson: also, you may be interested that mips and arm64 have a *named* zero register (`$zero` on mips, `xzr` on arm64).

Comment: I think it would be interesting to add to your answer _mm_set1_epi32 instead of _mm_setzero_si128. For example see the two answers to this question. One defines zero and ~zero (all ones) upfront and the other answer uses them in the intrinsics. Which method is better?

Comment: @Zboson: the two should be equivalent, given a non-stupid compiler (which, sadly, is sometimes too much to ask for).  However, trying to exert this level of control via intrinsics is an exercise in frustration; if you get one compiler to do what you want, others will do something else.  If you want to write assembly, write assembly.  Otherwise, let the compiler make these decisions.

Comment: I should also note that `~0` via `pcmpeqb reg, reg` is another dependency-breaking idiom, and so is often preferable to loading a vector of all ones.

Comment: yeah, GCC does `pcmpeqb reg, reg` for `_mm_set1_epi32(-1)` looking at the assembly. So I guess `0` at `-1` are special cases. `_mm_set1_epi32(2)` is not special.

Comment: If I read correctly from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981447/microarchitectural-zeroing-of-a-register-via-the-register-renamer-performance-v `pcmpeqb reg, reg` is treated like `xor reg,reg`. Does that mean there is no cost (no µops ) to do `pcmpeqb reg, reg` as well? I understand how `xop` can be costless if there is a physical zero register it is renamed to but `pcmpeqb reg, reg` produces all bits set. Is there a physical register with all bits set for this as well?

Comment: @Zboson: [quoting intel] "the micro-op must execute, however, since it is known that regardless of the input data the output data is always 'all ones' the micro-op dependency upon its sources does not exist as with the zero idiom and it can execute as soon as it finds a free execution port."

Comment: okay, I understand, it's not costless like zero but it does not have a dependency so it can be renamed.

Comment: I found this question interesting. I added an answer. If you have a chance to read it over let me know what you think.

Answer (score 5):

In regards to this particular operation you should do at Stephen Canon says and do

```
static inline Vec8s operator - (Vec8s const & a) {
    return _mm_sub_epi16(_mm_setzero_si128(), a);
}
```

That's taken directly from [Agner Fog's Vector Class Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass).

But let's consider what the `static` keyword does. When you declare a variable using `static` it uses static storage. This places it in the data section (which includes the .bss section) of your object file.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
extern "C" void foo2(__m128i a);

static const __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();

static inline __m128i negate(__m128i a) {
    return _mm_sub_epi16(zero, a);
}

extern "C" void foo(__m128i a, __m128i b) {
    foo2(negate(a));
}
```

I do `g++ -O3 -c static.cpp` and then look at the diassembly and sections. I see
there is a .bss section with a label `_ZL4zero`. Then there is a code startup section which writes the static variable in the .bss section.

```
.text.startup
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR _ZL4zero[rip], xmm0
    ret
```

The foo function

```
    movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR _ZL4zero[rip]
    psubw   xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
```

So GCC never uses a XMM register for the static variable. It reads from memory in the data section.

What if we did `_mm_sub_epi16(_mm_setzero_si128(),a)`? Then GCC produces for `foo`

```
    pxor    xmm1, xmm1
    psubw   xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
```

On Intel processors since Sandy Bridge the `pxor` is "free". On processors before that it's almost free. So this is clearly a better solution than reading from memory.

What if we tried `_mm_sub_epi16(_mm_set1_epi32(-1),a)`. In that case GCC produces

```
    pcmpeqd xmm1, xmm1
    psubw   xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
```

The `pcmpeqd` instruction is not `free` on any processor but it's still better than reading from memory using `movdqa`. Okay, so `0` and `-1` are special. What about `_mm_sub_epi16(_mm_set1_epi32(1)`)? In this case GCC produces for `foo`

```
    movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    psubw   xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
```

That's essentially the same as using a static variable! When I look at the sections I see that .LC0 points to a read only data section (.rodata).

Edit: here is a way to get GCC use use a [global variable in register](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html).

register __m128i zero asm ("xmm15") = _mm_set1_epi32(1);

This produces

```
movdqa  xmm2, xmm15
psubw   xmm2, xmm0
movdqa  xmm0, xmm2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zboson for clarifying this (and of course @StephenCanon)! I just encountered another case: there's no `_mm_abs_ps()`, and if you want to write a self-contained function emulating it, probably the fastest way would be to use `_mm_andnot_ps(signMask, x)` with `__m128 signMask = _mm_set1_ps(-0.0F)', the latter producing 4 times 0x80000000. So probably the fastest way (to avoid multiple `movdqa` inside the function) would be to pass the mask to my `_mm_abs_ps()` function?

Comment: @Ralf look in the [VCL](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) I mentioned in my answer. Look in the file `vectorf128.h`. Search for `abs`. If you don't find the answer you're looking for then post a question on SO. You should give Stephen Canon the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use vectors for efficiency, your code has a problem.

A static variable that isn't initialised with a constant will be initialised at runtime. In a thread safe way. The first time your inline function is called, the static variable is initialised. On every single call after that, a check is made whether the static variable needs initialising or not.

So on every call, there is a check, then there is a load from memory. If you don't use a static variable, there's probably a single instruction creating the value, plus plenty of opportunity for optimisation. Loading from memory is slow.

And you can have as many static variables as you like. The compiler will handle anything you throw at it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can add an interesting point to the discussion, particularly to my comment on _mm_abs_ps(). If I define

```
static inline __m128 _mm_abs_ps_2(__m128 x) {
  __m128 signMask = _mm_set1_ps(-0.0F);
  return _mm_andnot_ps(signMask, x);
}
```

(Agner Fog's VCL http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass uses an integer set1, a cast, and an AND operation instead, but that should in effect be the same) and use the function in a loop

```
float *p = data;
for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i += 4, p += 4)
  _mm_store_ps(p, _mm_abs_ps_2(_mm_load_ps(p)));
```

then gcc (4.6.3, -O3) is clever enough to avoid repeatedly executing _mm_set1_ps by **moving it outside the loop**:

```
    vmovaps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip] # tmp108,
    mov rax, rsp    # p,
.L3:
    vandnps xmm0, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax]   # tmp102, tmp108, MEM[base: p_54, offset: 0B]
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0 # MEM[base: p_54, offset: 0B], tmp102
    add rax, 16 # p,
    cmp rax, rbp    # p, D.7371
    jne .L3 #,
.LC1:
    .long   2147483648
    .long   2147483648
    .long   2147483648
    .long   2147483648
```

So, probably in most cases one shouldn't worry at all about repeatedly setting some xmm register to a constant inside some function.