# Mixing Assembly & Fortran plus parallelization (OpenMP)

Tags: assembly, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, race-condition

I am experimenting with the follwoing nowadays:

```
global  func_
func_:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rax,[rdi]
    mov rbx,[rsi]

    cmp rbx,1
    je  done
    dec rbx

    mov rsi,1
loop1:
    shl rsi, 1
    dec     rbx
    jnz     loop1

    or rax,rsi
    mov [rdi],rax

    mov rcx,15
    mov rax,11
    movq xmm1,rcx
    movq xmm0, rax
    xorpd xmm0, xmm1

    movq rax, xmm0
    mov [rdi],rax


    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

done:

    or rax,1
    mov [rdi],rax
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

The code so far doesn't really makes sense, I will need to use the XMM[] ( 128 bitwise operations ) and this assembly code should be compiled into an object and linked to a Fortran code where I will:

```
! Compile:
!gfortran -c testassembly.F90; 
!nasm -f elf64 assembly_func.asm; 
!gfortran -o run testassembly.o assembly_func.o; 
!./run

a = 10
b = 4
call func(a,b)
```

Up to this point everything is pretty clear, now what happens if I for eg. OpenMP parallize my code, namely:

```
!$omp do schedule(dynamic,1)
a = 10
b = 4
call func(a,b)
!$omp end do
```

In other words, do the registers in assembly exists physically? Or they will be somehow local to the OpenMP threads? If they are shared, how are the race conditions and stuff like that?

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Actually, the CPU has many more registers and even for a serial programs the names do not coincide with one distinct physical register in the core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each thread has its own set of registers. That's obvious in the case when threads execute on separate cores, since each core contains a full set of registers. When multiple threads are time-sharing the same physical core, the state of the user-visible registers is saved when execution switches to a different thread and then restored later on when the execution switches back to the original thread (context save/restore), thus giving the illusion that each thread operates exclusively on the registers.

As for the physical existence of those registers, modern x86 CPUs don't have fixed units in their cores called RAX, RBX, etc. They borrow from an old RISC concept and what they have instead is a large number of registers called a register file (actually, modern x86 CPUs are basically RISC cores with each CISC instruction being split into a set of simpler operations for the core called micro-ops). Each register from that file could serve as RAX through a process known as register renaming. This for example allows independent instructions to execute in parallel even if they use the same register, e.g.

```
mov [rdi], rax
xor rax, rax
```

In this case, the second instruction has no data dependency on the first one since the content of `rax` is simply being overwritten. But if there was a single RAX register, the CPU must first complete the write-to-memory stage of the first instruction before the second instruction could use RAX. With register renaming the second instruction simply writes to another register from the file that from then on serves as RAX.

Comment: One interesting thing I learned recently is that on Sandy Bridge xor rax, rax does not even use a micro-op. The register file has a zero register which the rax register is renamed to. The only cost is in decoding the instruction. But that's rarely a problem.

Comment: My original idea was `mov [rdi], rax; mov rax, [rsi]`, but then I decided to replace the second `mov` with something different. I didn't know about the zero register too.

Comment: In case you're interested I learned about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807285/are-static-static-local-sse-avx-variables-blocking-a-xmm-ymm-register/26808698#26808698