# What does this assembly code do? (TEST,XOR,JNZ)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

1.

```
TEST EAX,EAX
JNZ SHORT program.00407190
```

2.

```
XOR EAX,EAX
JNZ SHORT program.00407190
```

Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you! :)

From my understanding so far:

`JNZ` is jump if not equal to zero, it will jump or not depending on whether `ZF` is set to 1 or not. If it's 1, it will not jump. Else, it will jump.

From my understanding for code #1, `TEST EAX,EAX` will check whether it's zero or not. If it's not equal to zero(`ZF` is 0), it will jump to address 00407190.

For code #2 
`XOR EAX,EAX` will set EAX register to 0. Does it set any flags? If not, how does `JNZ` instruction determine to jump or not?

Lastly, why would people want to check if `EAX` is 0 or not? Kindly please assist me in a easier and detailed explanation, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: As for why you'd want to check if `EAX` is 0 or not; it depends on the context. Let's say that you're writing a Windows application and you called some WinAPI function, like `CreateWindow` or `HeapAlloc` or whatever. The result of the function (whether it's a window handle, a pointer to an allocated memory block, or something else) will be returned in `EAX`, and it makes sense to check whether the result was zero (invalid) or non-zero (valid), in order to determine how to proceed in your program.

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely a good example for beginners to relate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [x86 Assembly - 'testl' eax against eax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/x86-assembly-testl-eax-against-eax) for `test eax`, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396527/any-reason-to-do-a-xor-eax-eax for `xor`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TEST` and `XOR` are logical instructions used to perform logical operations on the operands.

**TEST INSTRUCTION** (comparing the operands)

```
TEST destiny, source
```

It performs a conjunction, bit by bit, of the operands, but differing from `AND`, this instruction does not place the result in the destination operand, it only has effect on the state of the flags.

```
Source Destiny | Destiny
--------------------------
1      1       | 1      
1      0       | 0
0      1       | 0
0      0       | 0    <---
```

---

**XOR INSTRUCTION** (Exclusive OR)

```
XOR destiny, source
```

Its function is to perform the logical exclusive disjunction of the two operands bit by bit.

```
Source Destiny | Destiny
--------------------------
1      1       | 0    <---
1      0       | 1
0      1       | 1
0      0       | 0    <---
```

---

As you see in the tables:

`XOR EAX,EAX` will set the `EAX` register to zero. The `ZF` will be set if the result of the `XOR` is zero. So in this case: (`ZF=1`)

`TEST EAX,EAX` does not place the result on the register, it only has effect on the state of the `ZF`. In this case if `EAX == 0`, then (`ZF=1`)

---

**JNZ (JNE) INSTRUCTION** (Conditional jump)

```
JNZ label
```

It jumps to `label` if it is not equal or zero. The jump will be done if `ZF` is deactivated. (`ZF=0`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but you missed out some of my questions.  For code #2 
XOR EAX,EAX will set EAX register to 0. Does it set any flags? If not, how does JNZ instruction determine to jump or not?

Lastly, why would people want to check if EAX is 0 or not?

Comment: @ysj `JNE` will be jumped if `ZF=0`. `XOR EAX,EAX` set `ZF=1`. Checking `EAX=0` is depend on your purpose.

Comment: @ysj `JNE` and `JNZ` are just different names for a conditional jump when `ZF` is equal to `0`