# x86 assembly language with ebx and bh

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

```
xor ebx,ebx
mov bh ,0x04 ;how to change that "bh" to "ebx" ,and keep  codes  same meaning?
```

and why people always use `xor` instead of `mov XXX,0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> xor ebx,ebx mov bh ,0x04;how to change that "bh" to "ebx" ,and keep codes same meaning?

Assuming I understand you correctly, what you want is this:

```
mov ebx, 0x0400
```

(`bh` is the upper 8 bits of `bx`, which is itself the lower 16 bits of `ebx`. So the value you need is the original value shifted left by 8, which we get by adding two hex 0 digits).

> why people always use xor instead of mov XXX,0 ?

To put it simply: because it's shorter and faster. See [What is the purpose of XORing a register with itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396527/any-reason-to-do-a-xor-eax-eax) and [Does using xor reg, reg give advantage over mov reg, 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135679/does-using-xor-reg-reg-give-advantage-over-mov-reg-0)

Answer (score 3):

Since `bh` is the second lowest byte of `ebx`, you can just do `mov ebx, 0x0400`.

`xor` is used because it's shorter opcode and the processors have special support to recognize it as zeroing the register. See the optimization manual, section *3.5.1.8 Clearing Registers and Dependency Breaking Idioms*.